# Highlight julia code in emacs

Tags: emacs, julia

I would like to write julialang code in emacs. Is there an easy way to do it like, for example, when you do python code (all these reserved words in colors and indentation)?

Here is what I have done so far:

I created the file

```
~/.emacs.d/init.el
```

with the line (after cloning https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/wiki/Julia):

```
(load "/path-to-ESS/ESS/lisp/ess-site.el")
```

julia is in my path also. Still, emacs does not recognize julia code

Comment: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/contrib/julia-mode.el

Answer (score 2):

I think that this may help. It seems to be emacs support for Julia.

[emacs-ess / ESS](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/wiki/Julia)

> Julia
>
> **Overview**
>   ESS support for julia language, among other things, includes
>   font-lock, indentation, sending code to sub-process, interactive
>   documentation, imenu, completion and eldoc.
>
> **Usage**
>   **Start**
>
> To start julia type M-x julia RET. You can start multiple julia
>   processes if you so desire.
>
> To autostart or switch form script to julia subprocess use C-c C-z. To
>   switch from process buffer to the most recent script buffer also use
>   C-c C-z. To associate a buffer with a different julia process press
>   C-c C-s.
>
> **Evaluation**
>
> To send chunks of code from your script use C-c C-c, C-M-x, C-RET etc.
>   To load the whole file: C-c C-l. See evaluating code section in ESS
>   manual. (tip: look up the documentation string of these commands with
>   for example C-h k C-c C-c)
>
> Help
>
> To access documentation for any help topic or object use C-c C-d C-d.
>   To call apropos: C-c C-d C-a. To look up for a topic in julia standard
>   library reference: C-c C-d C-r. To look up a topic in the julia
>   manual: C-c C-d m. To search julia website: C-c C-d C-w.
>
> To see all help commands defined in ess-doc-map: C-c C-d C-h. See Help
>   section in ESS documentation.

Comment: He is asking for `font-lock` support not for running the REPL.